# What is the best way to fill a model, with a value returned by a checkbox, that need to be stored in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, laravel

I’ve got a model property called ‘boolean_property’.
(The model below is, of course, an example. My real model has many more properties.)

```
<?php

class MyModel extends Model
{   
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'boolean_property' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

The value of this property is defined by the user in a form with a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name='boolean_property' {{ !$mymodel->boolean_property?: 'checked' }}>
```

If the checkbox is checked, the returned value is ‘on’(=string).
In my store (or update) route, I fill my model with the values returned by the form, and save it.

```
public function update(Request $request, MyModel $mymodel)
{
    $mymodel->fill($request->input());

    $mymodel->save();
    return redirect()->route('mymodels.edit', ['mymodel' => $mymodel]);
}
```

However, since the value of my ‘boolean_property’ is now ‘on’ (=string) MySQL is not very happy when I try to save that as a boolean in my database…

I can solve this problem this way :

```
public function update(Request $request, MyModel $mymodel)
{
    $mymodel->fill($request->input());
    $mymodel->done = $request->input('boolean_property') ? 1 : 0;
    $mymodel->save();
    return redirect()->route('mymodels.edit', ['mymodel' => $mymodel]);
}
```

But this solution isn’t very elegant since I must track down every part of my code where I fill my model with a checkbox value every time I want to add, change or delete a boolean property.

There is probably a better way to do this, by changing something in my model class, but I cannot find how.
That’s why I ask you, hoping that someone, more used to Laravel than me, can help me with that.

To sum up, my question is : **What is the best way to handle with Laravel a property, defined by a checkbox, that I want to use as a boolean in all my code, and be able to save it as a boolean (= tinyint) in my (MySQL) database ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mutator defined here https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

It would look like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the user's news letter preference.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setNewsletterAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['wants_newsletter'] = isset($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this solution, but I wrote 'setBooleanProperty' instead of 'setBooleanPropertyAttribute'... Anyway... It works much better now ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem anytime.